# Did hobbits go without shoes even in Caradhras?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, hobbits, clothing

As per question title. We all know hobbits don't wear shoes (and their feet are more adapted than ours to walking without protection), but was this true even in a chilly climate?

I find just a bit unbelievable that they had to fully cover themselves in winter clothes to withstand a full-blown snow blizzard (which they barely survived), and yet they were simply walking on ice and snow on their nude feet...

Comment: Agreed, I searched but didn't find that question. This one can be closed.